How can I fix my typescript type to work correctly?
How can I fix this Typescript type error that I'm getting?
Property 'original_title' does not exist on type 'Media'. and Property 'original_name' does not exist on type 'Media'.
I am getting data from an API and writing my own types for it. The API provides 2 different structures for Movies and TV Shows. TV Shows has name original_name origin country first_air_date and Movies has original_title release_date title video but both have a few other of the same properties so I wrote this type but am getting an error when using it.
I have a typescript type which looks like this:
export type Media = {
    adult: boolean;
    backdrop_path?: string;
    genre_ids: number[];
    id: number;
    original_language: string;
    overview: string;
    popularity: number;
    poster_path?: string;
    vote_average: number;
    vote_count: number;
} & (
    | {
            original_title: string;
            release_date: string;
            title: string;
            video: boolean;
      }
    | {
            first_air_date: string;
            name: string;
            origin_country: string[];
            original_name: string;
      }
);

However when trying to use it like this:
...
<View>
    {moviesData.results.map((result: Media) => (
        <Text key={result.id}>{result.original_title}</Text>
    ))}
</View>
<View>
    {showsData.results.map((result: Media) => (
        <Text key={result.id}>{result.original_name}</Text>
    ))}
</View>
...


you can try checking the type before accessing properties
eg check the media type then safely access properties
<View>
  {moviesData.results.map((result: Media) => (
    <Text key={result.id}>
      {'original_title' in result ? result.original_title : 'N/A'}
    </Text>
  ))}
</View>
<View>
  {showsData.results.map((result: Media) => (
    <Text key={result.id}>
      {'original_name' in result ? result.original_name : 'N/A'}
    </Text>
  ))}
</View>

